# Why does my predicate not work, when a similar predicate does?

Tags: prolog

I have the following facts:

```
loves(andy, julia).
loves(andrew, maria).
loves(bob, sofia).
loved(juila).
loved(maria).
loved(sofia).
```

and **I want to have two predicates:**

```
do_love(X, Y) :- ...
is_loved(X, Y) :- ...
```

**which returns Y as the name of the person, and X as the fact itself**. For the `loved` fact, I wrote:

```
is_loved(X, Y) :- X = loved(Y), X.
```

which as expected, returns:

```
is_loved(X,Y).
X = loved(juila),
Y = juila ;
X = loved(maria),
Y = maria ;
X = loved(sofia),
Y = sofia.
```

However, when I write the predicate for the `loves` fact in a similar way:

```
do_love(X, Y) :- X = loves(X, Y), X.
```

it returns false for the query:

```
do_love(X,Y).
false.
```

I'm new to prolog, and can't really see why this is the case. **Why does the query for `is_loved` work, while the one for `do_love` doesn't?**

Comment: Ask yourself this, what does `X = loved(Y)` do in Prolog? It's different from C# or Java.

Comment: And think about what `X = loves(X, Y)` means - you're trying to unify it as `X = loves(loves(X, Y), Y)`, which is then `X = loves(loves(loves(loves(X, Y), Y), Y), Y)`, etc. It can never be satisfied.

Comment: Which Prolog system are you using? If you are using SWI, try adding `:- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, error).` in front of your Prolog file, reload, and run your queries again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to unify `X` with *two* different values:

- `X = loves(...)` and
- `loves(X, ...)`

(I truncate using `...` because those parts are irrelevant to what I'm saying).

In other words, your `do_love` predicate is saying "X must unify with a `loves` predicate" *and also* "X must unify with the first argument in a `loves` predicate". With the data set you've set up, no single value fulfills both requirements.

Depending on what you're trying to do, this might be what you want:

```
do_love(X, Y) :- loves(X, Y).
```

**Sidenote 1:** Predicates don't "return" values like they do in other languages with functions. You don't need the `, X` in your predicates for them to work.

**Sidenote 2:** The `=` is a "unify" operator, rather than an "assignment" like other languages. See [this page](https://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a10unif.php) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link on unification, the examples have made its usage clearer, however, I'm still unsure how to proceed from here. The predicate you're suggesting, with the query loves(X,Y), would evaluate to e.g. X = andy, Y = julia. But what I want is X = loves(andy,julia), Y = julia (hence why I tried playing around with the equals/unification operator).

Comment: In that case you just need to use a separate variable. Something like `X = loves(Z, Y)`, or use an underscore if you don't care about its value like `X = loves(_, Y)`

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help.